# Django ORM: How to use count method inside values_list method?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

To simplify things, I need to perform this query:

```sql
 select state,count(*) from Airports group by state order by count(*) desc
```

And the desired return from my query is a dictionary like this:

```py
{
 'state1': value1,
 'state2': value2,
 'state3': value3,
        ...
 'staten': valuen,
}
```

I did some research and seems I need to use aggregate and annotate but I'm kinda lost in how to perform this with values_list().

Can I use count inside it like this?

```py
Airport.objects.values_list('state', Airport.objects.count()).annotate('state').order_by(-Airport.objects.count())
```

Comment: Follow the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset then put `values_list` to the very end of statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Airport.objects.values('state').annotate(count=Count('state')).order_by('-count')
```

Comment: This returned an exception:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'count' into field.

Comment: Still the same error. It complains about the 'count' inside values

Comment: To be precise with you: It returns: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'count' into field. Choices are: field1, field2, field3...

Comment: Errr... almost.. The counting is not precise? I need to count(*) and not the states ;)

Comment: Can I use Count('') ?

Comment: so the count should be how many airports are in each state right? And this does not work?